# whats the fastest way to copy data from table to new one?

Tags: oracle

Whats the fastest way to copy table "table_1" to new table called "table_2" ?

I'd like the constraints copied as well as the data.

Comment: create table table_2 as select * from table_1

Comment: @oldProgrammer but this will not copy the constrain am I right ?

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3725535/how-to-duplicate-a-table-with-all-its-constrains-in-sqlplus

Comment: Dont forget to use `append` and `parallel` hints for insert and select.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle 11g: performance improvements of inserts](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/37557/oracle-11g-performance-improvements-of-inserts)

Comment: @Colin a don't think this is a dupe of that because the OP is specifies that table_2 is a "new table"

Answer (score 1):

try alter table exchange partition, as this will not phsycaily move data but it will alter the dictionary, but keep in mind that the source table will be empty as this is exchnage

Comment: would you please to give me an example or link to read about that ?